# Specify the response value type from an axios request inside a saga

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, redux-saga

I'm fetching an api inside a saga with an axios instance(called http in the code), it works just fine but when I migrate the code to typescript (and installed the typed-redux-saga and babel-plugin-macros packages) the compiler says the result of this yield is unknown

```js
function* signIn ({ payload: { email, password } }: SignInProps) {
  try {
    const res = yield* call(http.post, `/signin`, { email, password }); // <-- res is unknown
    ...
  } catch (err) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I know that in axios I can pass a generic to specify the response value type this way:

```js
http.post<the response type>(myendpoint, bodyrequest)
```

but in the `call(fn, args)` syntax this does not work, ts gives me this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
The lat overload gave the following error.
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type
'{
  contest: unknown;
  fb: (this: unknown, ...args: any[]) => any;
}
```

The fix I find was to cast it to a SagaGenerator this way:

```js
const res = yield* call(http.post, `/signin`, { email, password }) as SagaGenerator<AxiosResponse<UserInfo>>;
```

then if I destructure the `data` prop from the response typescript correctly recognizes its type which is UserInfo.

But is there a more *organic* way to specify the response type instead of just casting it?

Answer (score 0):

[TypeScript: Use types on call() from redux-saga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522383/typescript-use-types-on-call-from-redux-saga)

Short answer, it appears no. This post does a great job explaining why that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help someone quickly solve this problem

```
interface Tokens {
  accessToken: string
  refreshToken: string
} 

interface Login {
  email: string,
  password: string
}

function* loginWorker({ payload }: { type: string, payload: Login }): Generator<PutEffect | CallEffect, void, AxiosResponse<Tokens>> {
  try {
    const response: AxiosResponse<Tokens> = yield call(loginApi, payload);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const data = response.data
      yield put(loginSuccess(data));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(loginError());
  }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers.  Include text that explains how the code solves the problem.